# Can I delete the Windows 10 boot partition without losing my documents and data?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation

Windows 10 blanked out on my computer and now I need to install Ubuntu to recover my data.

I want to delete the Windows 10 boot partition (9.5 GB) because it doesn’t work anyways and I need the extra space to finish the Ubuntu install. I just don’t want to lose my data on the main hard drive.

[image: Partition table]

Comment: It looks like NTFS partition may be hibernated. Then you can only manually mount read only using Linux NTFS driver. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partition is weird, an EFI boot partition is max. ~1G and is never in NTFS.

This must be a data partition, spin up the live USB OS run on the terminal

```bsh
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
cd /mnt
ls
```

If it fails do `apt install -y ntfs-3g` and retry

If it is empty you can just delete it, othewise have a backup before deleting

Comment: I know that partition doesn’t have any of my data on it. I’m just wondering if my data is reliant on the Windows OS. Like, if I delete the OS, if my data will be gone.

Comment: No, not at all, if you're sure that no data sits on that partition, feel free to delete it, you'll still be able to access it